# Virtual Box not working after upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04

Tags: upgrade, virtualbox

I had Oracle Virtual Box installed with Win 98 loaded into it.  It was working fine when I had Ubuntu 12.10 and recently I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04.  After that I am not able to Start the WIN 98 OS and getting an error stating "Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)".  Please help in getting this fixed.  Thanks.

Regards
PK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your problem, execute the following command in a terminal:

`sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`

Comment: *Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMS                                                               Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.8.0-19-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
 * Failed, trying without DKMS

Comment: While I executed the command i got the above error.  I am now trying to install the linux-headers-generic package.  I did a search in internet for the same pakage of 3.8.0.19 and found that to belong to Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Hi,  After Installing the linux-headers-generic package, the VM is working fine now.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, glad it worked! I never experienced the error you had, maybe because I also always add Dynamic Kernel Module Support after installing Virtual Box (so kernel update does not break it), but I am not sure: 
# sudo apt-get install dkms

Answer (score 0):

I know is a old topic, but I had the same issue with Ubuntu 22.04, as far as my knowledge go, is because of the Secure Boot.

I tried troubleshooting running virtualbox through temrinal, so I got a message that suggested me to run

```
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

that helped me to put a signature to the kernel driver (again, if I got it right) with a guided procedure.

So far everything is working fine,I wish this could help